# Unique objects in arraylist by multiple properties (PS)

Tags: powershell

How can i get unique records by two (or more) properties?
i have ArrayList of objects of type :

```
class Something
{
[string] $Name
[string] $Key
[string] $SomethingElse
[string] $Val
}
```

and i would like to select only unique items from this array list, by `$name,$key,$somethingelse`

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe your list to `group-object` like this:

```
$List | Group-Object Name, Key, Somethingelse | Where-Object Count -eq 1 | Select-Object -Expand Group
```

`Group-Object` creates groups object with equal properties. You can filter the groups by their count and/or their properties. After that, you can get the groups content by expanding the `Group` property